# fadeIn / fadeOut effect in select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I'm using [**select2**](https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)  jQuery , i want fadeIn and fadeOut effect on click on select2 open and on close , or any other animation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For smooth animation i have change jQuery file

Replace `this.dropdown.show();` with `this.dropdown.slideDown("slow");`

and `this.dropdown.hide();` with `this.dropdown.slideUp("slow");`

reference [link](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-animate-select2-dropdown/)

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor It won't change style of select2. It just change animation.

Comment: Wierd, then it must be for older version of the plugin

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor Can you share page link and describe what issue you're facing ?

Comment: Sure, first of all i use Select2 4.0.x so its No longer use this.dropdown.show() so i try the code you linked too, But that use some totalt diffrent style and class name

https://jsfiddle.net/Ranazomic/kjn1a9wv/1/